# "followed a science and gone through it" in Greenmantle?

Tags: meaning, john-buchan, greenmantle

In [Greenmantle](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/559/pg559-images.html#chap09), by John Buchan, Hannay, a British officer, was on a secret mission in Turkey during First World War. Now he's asked by a German woman why he come to Turkey:

> “What came you forth to seek?” she asked. “You are not like the stout American Blenkiron, a lover of shoddy power and a devotee of a feeble science. There is something more than that in your face. You are on our side, but you are not of the Germans with their hankerings for a rococo Empire. You come from America, the land of pious follies, where men worship gold and words. I ask, what came you forth to seek?”
>
> As she spoke I seemed to get a vision of a figure, like one of the old gods looking down on human nature from a great height, a figure disdainful and passionless, but with its own magnificence. It kindled my imagination, and I answered with the stuff I had often cogitated when I had tried to explain to myself just how a case could be made out against the Allied cause.
>
> “I will tell you, Madam,” I said. “I am a man who **has followed a science, but I have followed it in wild places, and I have gone through it and come out at the other side**. The world, as I see it, had become too easy and cushioned. Men had forgotten their manhood in soft speech, and imagined that the rules of their smug civilization were the laws of the universe. But that is not the teaching of science, and it is not the teaching of life. We have forgotten the greater virtues, and we were becoming emasculated humbugs whose gods were our own weaknesses. Then came war, and the air was cleared. Germany, in spite of her blunders and her grossness, stood forth as the scourge of cant. She had the courage to cut through the bonds of humbug and to laugh at the fetishes of the herd. Therefore I am on Germany’s side. But I came here for another reason. I know nothing of the East, but as I read history it is from the desert that the purification comes. When mankind is smothered with shams and phrases and painted idols a wind blows out of the wild to cleanse and simplify life. The world needs space and fresh air. The civilization we have boasted of is a toy-shop and a blind alley, and I hanker for the open country.”

I take this as "he used a scientific approach" but I can't understand what's meant by "gone through it" nor the whole meaning of this bold sentence.

Answer (score 1):

He means that he has not only followed science, he has followed it first, through all the difficult parts of it ("wild places") and second, so far that he has come to see its weaknesses and limitations.  Thus, he metaphorically "come out at the other side" -- he has utterly superseded it, and its limits.